# Equivalent of PropertyInfo.IsPublic in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, system.reflection, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to get all public properties in the below type.
In .NET Framework I'd to that by using `IsPublic` from the `PropertyInfo` type but that does not seem to exist in .NET Core 2.

```
internal class TestViewModel
{
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

//how can I retrieve an IEnumerable with PropertyOne and PropertyTwo ONLY?
var type = typeof(TestViewModel);
var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(p => /*p.IsPublic &&*/ !p.IsSpecialName);
```

Comment: @mjwills Not a duplicate since that SO answer recommends TypeExtensions, which does not work with .NET Core 2.0 (apparantly).

Comment: @mjwills I'm at fault here, I edited the question and made it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use the PropertyType member, as such..
`Programmer().GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsPublic && p.DeclaringType == typeof(Programmer));`

```
    public class Human
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Programmer : Human
    {
        public int YearsExperience { get; set; }
        private string FavLanguage { get; set; }
    }
```

This successfully returns only the public int YearsExperience.

Comment: That does not seem to work, it returns every public property from all inherited types.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work! While the below answer also works, I'll mark yours as the answer since you have lower reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use binding flags as in "classical" .NET

```
    //how can I retrieve an IEnumerable with PropertyOne and PropertyTwo ONLY?
    var type = typeof(TestViewModel);
    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the enumeration is empty with only `BindingFlags.Public` and it contains every public property including inherited onces when it's both flags.

Comment: This method works as expected. If you want to get only propereties declared in `TestViewModel` (not inherited), you should use `var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);`

Comment: I marked the above answer as the solution, yours work aswell but he had lower reputation, is that alright? Otherwise I wouldn't know how to choose...

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class TestViewModel
{
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }

    private string PrivateProperty { get; set; }
    internal string InternalProperty { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //how can I retrieve an IEnumerable with PropertyOne and PropertyTwo ONLY?
        var type = typeof(TestViewModel);

        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (var p in properties)
            //only prints out the public one
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }
}
```

You can specify:

```
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance
```

to get other types